# Passport.js req.user object is undefined after server side file changes (node, express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using passport.js to authenticate the user to my app, but I have noticed that after any changes on server files, req.user is undefined.
Nodemon is correctly reloading all the files but after I hit refresh - an app is broken and req.user is undefined.
What is important: it only happens when server-side files are changed. When there are no changes I can refresh many times and everything works well.

This is my config code:

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.EXPRESS_SESSION_KEY,
    unset: 'destroy',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, credentials: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: FRONTEND_URL,
    credentials: true
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static('../../dist'));
```

I can't find any solution. It's pretty annoying to rebuild the whole app after any file change on the server side.

I can also notice that req.session is empty after file changes. Why is that?

Comment: Don't you think you should save sessoion in db so that even after restarting server sessions will not break and you will get req.use perfectly\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified [the `store` property](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#store), so Express Session will default to using a `MemoryStore`. This keeps session data in memory, so when you change the server side code and trigger a reload of the server, the session store is wiped and all session data is lost.

Use [a different session store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores) (such as [session file store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store)) which stores the data somewhere persistent.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin for your tip, was helpful! Gonna implement that in coming tasks!

Answer (score -1):

Use below link to and see see there is some thing  called **Store**.
Use that which actually storing using passportjs sessions

https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-authentication-passport-js/